# Telegram Login Widget expiration time

Tags: cookies, telegram, telegram-bot

I am using the Telegram Login Widget in my web app, but it looks like it's setting a cookie with an expiration of 6 months.

I would like to set the login session expiration date to 24 hours, but I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone know how?

Thanks